# ffmpeg overlay whith audio filter showcqt

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

I want to overlay a video with the showcqt effect on the right corner, I know that I have to use a filter graph but don't know how, the documentation is large but not very accessible for me. `ffmpeg` outputs this:

```sh
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'cover.webm':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.20.100
  Duration: 00:03:14.58, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 206 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: vp9 (Profile 0), yuv420p(tv, bt709), 1280x720, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:03:14.541000000
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:03:14.581000000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [showcqt](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#showcqt) and [overlay](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -filter_complex "showcqt=s=320x180[cqt];[0][cqt]overlay=main_w-overlay_w:main_h-overlay_h" -c:a copy output.webm
```

The audio is [stream copied](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) (`-c:a copy`) in this example to avoid re-encoding. Remove `-c:a copy` if you want it to automatically re-encode to an appropriate audio format for whatever output container you choose.